# Getting all reviews from a steam game using Steamworks but always return the same page?

Tags: json, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

Currently, I am trying to get all the steam reviews from a particular game, using the method described in the Steamworks documentation: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews

However, when I try to get reviews for a game like Dota 2 for example using the method: 
http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/570?json=1&start_offset=9200
http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/570?json=1&start_offset=9220

I always got the same return after a small offset. There should be more than 878,134 reviews for Dota 2. Why I got the same return before reaching the end? Thanks.

Comment: Are they putting all reviews to the API?

Answer (score 1):

Not all reviews can be accessed with the method described in https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews . For example, for now, there are 18 reviews in http://store.steampowered.com/app/794820/Knights_of_Pen_and_Paper_2_Free_Edition/. But there is nothing in http://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/794820?json=1.

Comment: Naah! That's cause it's a free game. And the default `purchase_type` as per the documentation  is `steam` ie reviews written by users who paid for the product on Steam (default)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify day_range. Try set day_range=9223372036854775807
source https://www.reddit.com/r/devsteam/comments/7qxjho/steam_api_user_reviews_query/